# Complex word order : ( time - manner - place) followed by direct and indirect object

Tags: word-order

Hello guys I will write Complex word order and tell me if iam right or wrong and if there another right sort?

> 1-Ich habe gestern mit meiner Hand in der Schule dem Schüler den Bleistift gegeben.

> 2- Ich habe gestern mit meiner Hand in der Schule ihm den Bleistift gegeben.

> 3- Ich habe gestern mit meiner Hand in der Schule ihn ihm gegeben.

> 4-  gestern habe ich mit meiner Hand in der Schule ihn ihm gegeben.

> 5- ihn habe ich gestern mit meiner Hand in der Schule ihm gegeben.

> 6- ihm habe ich gestern mit meiner Hand in der Schule den Bleistift gegeben.

> 7-mit meiner Hand habe ich gestern in der Schule ihn ihm gegeben.

> 8- mit meiner Hand habe ich gestern in der Schule  dem Schüler den Bleistift gegeben.

> 9- In der Schule habe ich gestern mit meiner Hand ihn ihm gegeben.

Comment: I don't think the close votes are appropriate here. My interpretation is that the poster is asking for general guidelines on word order rather than translation request or grammar check. Perhaps the question isn't worded as well as it could be for this purpose, but this is a new contributor after all. I think the "don't stomp on the newbies" rule should take precedence over the "don't ask for grammar checks" rule.

Comment: In any case, *Hand* is feminine, so it should be *mit meiner Hand*

Comment: None of your examples are wrong. If you stick with "time, manner, place" you will be using the "standard adverbials order". With practice, you will be developing a "feel" of when it's reasonable to change this order. Without that practice, you might be putting a non-intended emphasis on specific aspects, but that's still not wrong.

Comment: Nice example of the dying use of the past tense ...

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to German SE! This sentence is obviously somewhat contrived, in other words constructed to fit in as many types of adverbial phrases as possible. The problem is that there is no single correct answer to this kind of thing without context; much depends on what the speaker feels is important, new information, or should be emphasized for some other reason. There is a "neutral" word order, but I think with a sentence this complex a strict adherence to these guidelines (and they are guidelines, not rules) would be unlikely.

One kind of "hack" you can apply with this kind of thing is to put the adverb of time first if there is one. This will reduce the problem by one, and the subject normally comes right after the verb if it's not in front of the verb. So I think *Gestern habe ich* would be a good guess for the start of the sentence.

Some of your examples use *dem Schüler* as the dative object and some use *ihm*, and this makes a difference. If you're referring to something as a pronoun then, by definition, it's not new information. So *ihm* would most likely come soon after the subject with the more specific information coming later in the sentence where it has more emphasis. (While English usually puts less important information at the end when there's a choice, in German it normally goes in the middle.) Similarly, some of your examples use *den Bleistift* and some use *ihn* and you'd apply the same rule of thumb.

Some German grammars get very specific about word order and want you to memorize the positions of a dozen "slots", the accusative pronoun slot, the time adverb slot, etc. My thinking is such detail is of dubious value; at best it describes a neutral word order which would often be thrown out in practice. German word order is flexible, so if you're not taking things like emphasis into account then you're probably getting it wrong despite all the slots. Native German speakers definitely aren't keeping such a system in their head and are going by what "feels" the most natural. As a learner you have to develop a similar "feeling" for the correct word order. A few rules of thumb will help you avoid the most glaring mistakes until you develop your own sense of "feel" for it, but the rules of any natural language tend to be rather fuzzy, and sometimes the best answer you can get is one version "sounds a bit more natural" than another version rather than one version is right and the other is wrong.

Comment: Danke für diese ausführlichen Informationen! Das hat mir wirklich helfen.. So Ich soll sagen :   gestern habe ich ihn ihm mit meiner Hand in der Schule gegeben. // gestern  habe ich ihm mit meiner Hand in der Schule den Bleistift gegeben. // gestern  habe ich ihn mit meiner Hand in der Schule dem Schüler gegeben. // sind diese richtig?

Comment: While your remarks about the "feel" for proper WO in your last paragraph is correct, there's another "feel" that triggers much earlier with most native speakers, that would tell you something like "I'm riding myself into a complicated mess here, better stop it". While it's perfectly possible and valid in German to over-decorate a sentence with all sorts of adverbials of time, place, manner, and what-have-you, we simply avoid it.

Comment: @Khaled: The use of past tense instead could simplify things.